# Deploying On-send Outlook Addins on Mac devices

Tags: macos, office365, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

We are working on an Outlook add-in that uses the On-send feature (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/outlook-on-send-addins?tabs=unix). We want to know what our options are when it comes to deploying this add-in to actual users, with the focus being on users running Outlook on Mac. Per documentation, On-send Add-ins are not allowed on AppSource. The ideal flow we are looking for is one where there's little to no manual action required on behalf of either the end-users or the Admins.

1. Is there a way to deploy the add-in automatically on the end-user device (running Mac), with neither any admin-side action required, nor any manual action required by the user -- e.g., by downloading the Add-in manifest, and running a script on the device?

   - I'm aware user can sideload the manifest once the manifest is downloaded, but this is not acceptable in our case; we are looking for a way where the installation of the add-in is automated, without requiring any manual action on behalf of the user.
2. If the above is not an option, what is the recommended way to deploy the add-in? I found two links from MS, with possibly conflicting info; which of these two is the right one to try?

   - The first one is "Publish Office Add-ins using Centralized Deployment via the Office 365 admin center" from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/centralized-deployment#end-user-experience-with-add-ins. Looks like this is supposed to be done from the O365 Admin Console --> Settings > Services & add-ins.

     - This approach requires (from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/admin/manage/centralized-deployment-of-add-ins?view=o365-worldwide) the following as pre-requisites; are all of them actually required?

       - "have Exchange Online and active Exchange Online mailboxes" -- is there a difference between "Exchange Online" and "active Exchange Online mailboxes"?
       - "Version 1701 or later of Office 365 ProPlus." -- does this apply for Mac as well? If so, is there such a version for Mac?
       - "Your subscription'd directory must either be in, or federated to Azure Active Directory."
     - Looks like there's a Powershell-based alternative to this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/enterprise/use-the-centralized-deployment-powershell-cmdlets-to-manage-add-ins. Is this subject to the same requirements as the above?
   - The second flow, which is more geared towards Outlook (rather than the other Office apps) is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/add-ins-for-outlook/specify-who-can-install-and-manage-add-ins?redirectedfrom=MSDN. This is to be initiated from Exchange admin center under Organization > Add-ins > New Add Icon

     - Does this work with a non-ProPlus O365 subscription as well?
     - Does this work outside of Azure AD?
3. (Assuming Bullet 1. is not an option so we have to go with 2.) After deploying add-in from admin, is further action required to activate it on the end-user device?

   - Per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/centralized-deployment#end-user-experience-with-add-ins:"For Outlook 2016 or later, users can do the following: In Outlook, choose Home > Store. Choose the Admin-managed item under the add-in tab. Choose the add-in, and then choose Add."
4. (Again assuming Bullet 1. is not an option so we have to go with 2.) Is there API support to help automate bullets 2 and 3?